Trying to SSH into Ubuntu VPS from powershell, keep recieving public key error
I read through some other threads of similar issues but none of the solutions worked (haven't tried overwriting the public key as I don't know if that will lock me out or cause other issues, if this is a quick fix I'll do it right away). I am running a Linode nanode VPS with Ubuntu 24.04 on it and am trying to SSH into it from Powershell. I used ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096, created a public-private key pair stored in C:\Users\me/.ssh/id_rsa. I ran ssh -v username@hostname and received the following log
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xx [xxx.xxx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 172.105.97.31:22 as 'me'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: bwah25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: awaw-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: KEYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
KEEEEEYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2->nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa->sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: ping@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
KEYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory

I'm not sure what is causing this error and any help is appreciated. If I just need to make a new key and send it to my server again (a pain on powershell since ssh-copy-id doesn't work...) I will, just need advice on this matter.

You need to get a copy of C:\Users\me\.ssh\id_rsa.pub from your windows machine appended to ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys on your VPS.

It already is there. Nano'd into the authorized keys and verified, it's copied exactly

OK, might be permissions. ~/.ssh should probably be mode 700, authorized_keys should not have write access except for owner

You might want to confirm line-ending character(s), cat -vet filename will show text ... $ or text ... ^M$. If you see ^M$ run your authorized_keys thru dos2unix authorized_keys to convert to unix/linux std text ...$ formatting.(maybe you want to make a backup before doing that).  (The $ just represents the \n line-ending char, making it visible. You won't see a real $ char in you file unless you use an editor or utility (cat) that makes them explicit.)

There's a line in the debug output saying debug1: Authenticating to 172.105.97.31:22 as 'me'.  This suggests it is trying to connect to the Ubuntu user account named me.  Does your Ubuntu VPS really have a user named 'me'?  That's extremely unusual in Unix/Linux installations.  If there's no such user in the VPS then it will reject all attempts to authenticate no matter which key you try.

For the vetting, I ran the key through dos2unix however I still receive the same message when running ssh -v user@hostname.

For the 'me' username that was an attempt to obscure my username, I have a valid one in the OS.
